# Sylius missing translations

Tags: translation, sylius

I'm currently busy on a new installation of Sylius but the Dutch translation is just 80% complete which results in a few missing strings like 'sylius.report.no_data' and such.

Now I've discovered the Crowdin and already contributed a bit but now I want to update my own installation first.

I've seen that Sylius uses jms/translation-bundle in the composer so I tried to add the WebUI using:

```
JMSTranslationBundle_ui:
    resource: @JMSTranslationBundle/Controller/
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /_trans
```

But this gives me following error:

```
Cannot load resource "@JMSTranslationBundle/Controller/". Make sure the "JMSTranslationBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. If the bundle is registered, make sure the bundle path "@JMSTranslationBundle/Controller/" is not empty.
```

Registering the bundle again in AppKernel.php is also not working...
Or should I just edit the yml files?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the translations in the yml and clear cache, that would be enough.
So in your `app/Resources/translation/messages.nl.yml` or `src/Acme/Resources/translation/message.nl.yml` translate the needed strings eg.:

```
sylius:
    add_to_cart: Your translation
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that indeed editing them in my messages.nl.yml in the Resources folder will be the way to go if I need them fast.